# Python Merge Pandas Datasets via inner join with two fields

Tags: python, join, inner-join

I am brand new within the community, so I hope you pay patience a little bit.
I am trying to merge two datasets by using an inner join on the fields "Postal Code" and "Date".
The orgininal code would be like this:

```
Datapump = pd.merge(hack, health, how='inner', left_on=['Date', 'CP'], right_on=['Creation', 'cp'])
```

But the point is that I get an empty dataset whenever I tried to perform an head and worst an error in case to perform a sample:
So I have put as indexes the field 'Date' for hack and the field 'Creation' for health. Then I go for the join.

```
Datapump = pd.merge(hack, health, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Unfortunately I need as well the field postal code. So I do another join at the following point
`Datapump = pd.merge(hack, health, how='inner', left_on=['CP'], right_on=['cp'])`

Now I can get the sample and the head, but anything is going weird according to me, especially once I see the number of entries of the new dataset:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Int64Index: 803206 entries, 0 to 803205
Data columns (total 15 columns):
CP                   803206 non-null object
Tipo Contaminante    803206 non-null int64
Valor                803206 non-null float64
Verified             803206 non-null object
nombre               803206 non-null object
edad                 801296 non-null object
cp                   803206 non-null object
patologia            802387 non-null object
created              803206 non-null datetime64[ns]
Edad_Cat             786829 non-null category
Duration             772661 non-null timedelta64[ns]
Duration_Seconds     772661 non-null float64
weekdays_created     803206 non-null int64
month                803206 non-null float64
cat_month            803206 non-null int64
dtypes: category(1), datetime64ns, float64(3), int64(3), object(6), timedelta64ns
memory usage: 92.7+ MB

Actually before health had roughly 9000 entries and hack roughly 6000 entries.
It cannot be that I get a dataset of 803.206 entries, by performing an inner join.

How can I do this inner join in a way that it can provide a meaningful and reasonable result?

Thank a lot for the patience.

Andrea

Comment: provide few rows in the data frames to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

eventually I was able to solve the issue. The issue was due to a problem inside the data frame. I open the orginial csv file and manually I clean the problematic rows. Then I re-import the new file and I was able to carry out the join.
Regards,
Andrea

Comment: Issue is closed